# StackOverflowError caused by class declaring subclass?

Tags: java, class, stack-overflow, subclass

I am working on a project that uses a class and some subclasses. When I declare my `Database` class, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at data.DatabaseConnectionHandler.<init>(DatabaseConnectionHandler.java:12)
    at data.Database.<init>(Database.java:18)
```

These last two lines repeat themselves for about another 10000 times.

`Database` is my parent class and `DatabaseConnectionHandler` is the subclass. In the `Database` class, I declare a instance of `DatabaseConnectionHandler`, I think this might be the cause, but I don't know why.

`Database` Class:

```
public class Database {

    protected static Connection connection = null;
    protected static Statement statement = null;
    protected static ResultSet resultSet = null;

    DatabaseConnectionHandler DBCH = new DatabaseConnectionHandler(); //Line 18
    Registration regis = new Registration();

    public Database() throws SQLException {

        DBCH.openConnection();

    }
```

And `DatabaseConnectionHandler` Class:

```
public class DatabaseConnectionHandler extends Database {

    private final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foo_bar";
    private final String USERNAME = "foo";
    private final String PASSWORD = "bar";

    public DatabaseConnectionHandler() throws SQLException {} //line 12

    protected void openConnection() {

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

        connectionStatus = true;

    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException exe) {

        System.out.println(exe);

        connectionStatus = false;

    }

}
```

Is `Database()` declaring `DatabaseConnectionHandler()` causing this error? If so, how do I fix this and if not, what is causing the problem then and how do I fix that?

Comment: Every Database creates a DatabaseConnectionHandler, which is also a Database, so it also creates a DatabaseConnectionHandler, which is also a Dabase, so it also creates a DatabaseConnectionHandler, which is also a Dabase, so it also creates a DatabaseConnectionHandler, which is also a Dabase, so it also creates a DatabaseConnectionHandler, which is also a Dabase, so it also creates a DatabaseConnectionHandler, which is also a Dabase, so it also creates a DatabaseConnectionHandler, which is also a Dabase... See where this is going?

Comment: I thought so, too, but I can't see any sign of DatabaseConnectionHandler creating a Database in my code

Comment: @JvanAmerongen What do you think `DatabaseConnectionHandler DBCH = new DatabaseConnectionHandler();` is doing, if not creating a Database?

Comment: @azurefrog The given code creates a new DatabaseConnectionHandler, but DatabaseConnectionHandler does not create a Database

Comment: A DatabaseConnectionHandler *is a Database*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a `Database`, you also create a `DatabaseConnectionHandler`:

```
public class Database {

    //...
    DatabaseConnectionHandler DBCH = new DatabaseConnectionHandler();
    //...

}
```

And a `DatabaseConnectionHandler` is a `Database`:

```
public class DatabaseConnectionHandler extends Database {

    //...

}
```

So creating a `Database` requires creating a `Database`.  This is an infinite recursion.

You have two options:

1. Don't create a `DatabaseConnectionHandler` when creating a `Database`
2. Don't have a `DatabaseConnectionHandler` itself be a `Database`

Comment: So when a DBCH (for short) is created, it _also_  creates another Database. When I create a new Database, does it also creates a DBCH then? And how about making the methods in DBCH `static` and not creating a DBCH?

Comment: @JvanAmerongen: A `DatabaseConnectionHandler` doesn't create a `Database`, it *is* a `Database`.